# При выборе несистемного QFileDialog слетает кодировка некоторых системных файлов/папок

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка, qt5

При выборе опции `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` в диалоговом окне слетает кодировка некоторых системных файлов/папок, без этой опции всё хорошо, хотя некоторые названия в кириллице пишутся нормально, тот же рабочий стол на скрине или домашняя папка.

`codecForName` не помогает.

Скопировав символы закинул в определитель кодировки, он выдал cp1251, которая и стояла, и
верную надпись, т.е. проблема не в названии или ещё чем.

Подскажите, как можно исправить или хоть в чем ошибка?

[image: Диалоговое окно]

Comment: надо всё делать в utf8